# nginx regex for location, specific file caching

Tags: regex, nginx, location

I need to cache specific files in nginx reverse proxy, but in origin server, they (developers) made many subfolders. I need some regex pointer for locations so i can locate cacheable files.

I copied this [site's](https://www.chanhvuong.com/2887/node-js-express-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-cache/) nginx config.

Sample of `nginx.conf`:

```
location /product/categoryA {
   proxy_pass http://somewhere:8081;
}
location ~* ^/product/categoryA/(.+\.(woff2|woff|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|js|html|htm))$ {
    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    add_header X-Powered-By DCU;
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://somewhere:8081;
}
```

Examples for cacheable files:

```
domainabc.com/product/categoryA/desktop/css/somecssfile.css
domainabc.com/product/categoryA/desktop/runable/js/somejsfile.js
```

Using above location, those `.css` and `.js` files will not be found.

I need help for regex in location so nginx can locate those files without hard-coding the subfolders ( *../desktop/css, ../desktop/runable/js* )

I still need "**/product/categoryX**" since there are still other categories but with a different origin server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the following regex `^/product/categoryA/(.+\.woff2|woff|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|js|html|htm))$` due to `^` at the begining will only catch things that start with `/product` at the begining of the line or string. If you remove the `^` it should catch the string you want.

On the same not the `$` means that it is the end of line or string and there is notheing after it so if you have something after `.css` or `.js` might not catch them as well.

Comment: already try to remove "^" , still  cannot catch those files. and /product/categoryX is a must, because that's the way to differentiate origin server.